# Samsung Galaxy S3 Neo shows the logo, then screen turns black

Tags: samsung

So basically today I was going home, started listening to some music and BAM the music stops. The phone "turns on" and shows the Samsung Galaxy S3 neo gt something and then the screen turns black. And that happens in an infinite loop. It also happens when charging and when I remove the battery and put it back in, it automatically boots up, shows the logo and turns black. What do I do?

Answer (score -1):

Probably the battery is dead, try to plug in a new one

Comment: I don't really think so because the battery I am using right now is only 1 month old